# Location of VCS Line Modifications in Editor (PHPStorm)

Tags: phpstorm

My editor has modified line markers in the editor (added / changed / deleted) appearing.

However, I switched configs, and it is now located in the RIGHT of the editor.

[image]

Previously, this was in the LEFT of the editor, next to the line numbers.

Even worse then where its located now, is that this view on the right is not lined up with what is in view of the editor, but rather it shows it in the context the "overview" of the document.

I much prefer the left as I look there far more often, and I like it to be next to the line number that is affected.

Any help?

I am using the 8.0-EAP version. Previously I was using v7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

The colors on the right side do not seem to be VCS related.

The gutter/eft-side colors are present if VCS is enabled and can be edited in the Settings -> Editor -> Colors and Fonts -> General settings panel, with the colors named "Added Lines" and "Modified Lines".